# How do I get multiple outputs from an object using Javascript in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, object, attributes

I'm trying to output all of the possibilities of an object's attributes using a filter. The user picks a platform and a genre of a game, and it outputs the name, picture, and description. If I have multiple games that fall under the same platform and genre I want them all listed. In the console they do, but when I output them to the html document I only get the first name, picture and description listed.

**JavaScript**

```
var games=[{name:'Forza',platform:'xbox',genre:'Racing',descr:'Description',imgr:'forza.jpg'},
{name:'Need For Speed',platform:'xbox',genre:'Racing',descr:'Description',imgr:'nfs.jpg'}

var genre;
var platform;
$("#platformType").change(function(){
    platform=$(this).val()
})
$("#genreType").change(function(){
    genre=$(this).val()
})
$("#Submit").click(function(){games.filter((e)=>e.platform==platform && e.genre==genre?document.getElementById("theGame").innerHTML = e.name:false)})
$("#Submit").click(function(){games.filter((e)=>e.platform==platform && e.genre==genre?document.getElementById("pic").innerHTML = pic.setAttribute("src", e.imgr):false)})
$("#Submit").click(function(){games.filter((e)=>e.platform==platform && e.genre==genre?document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML = e.descr:false)})
```

**HTML:**

```
    <label for="platformType">
        Platform
    </label>
    <select name="platform" id="platformType">
        <option value="PC">(Choose Platform)</option>
        <option value="PC">PC</option>
        <option value="PS4">Playstation 4</option>
        <option value="switch">Switch</option>
        <option value="xbox">Xbox One</option>  
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />

    <label for="genreType">
        Genre
    </label>
    <select name="genre" id="genreType">
        <option value="PC">(Choose Genre)</option>
        <option value="Action">Action/Adventure</option>
        <option value="Fighter">Fighter</option>
        <option value="MMO">MMO</option>
        <option value="MOBA">MOBA</option>
        <option value="OpenWorld">Open World</option>
        <option value="Platformer">Platformer</option>
        <option value="Racing">Racing</option>
        <option value="RPG">RPG</option>
        <option value="Shooter">Shooter</option>
        <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />

    <input type="submit" value="Find Game" id="Submit" />

    </br >
        <h1 id="theGame"></h1>
    </br >
        <img id="pic" src="q.jpg"/>
    </br >
        <p id="desc"></p>
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more, or at least include more code? because this code doesn't print to the console as is. I'm guessing you only copy and pasted part of your code in?

Comment: Yeah I will sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following filter function could be used to accomplish your goal. There are a few issues in the code you provided, which is causing the code not to accomplish what you want.

Updated JS:

```
var games=[
  {name:'Forza',
   platform:'xbox',
   genre:'racing',
   descr:'Description',
   imgr:'forza.jpg'},
  {name:'Need For Speed',
   platform:'xbox',
   genre:'racing',
   descr:'Description',
   imgr:'nfs.jpg'}];

/* make sure you add a default value to these variables to avoid errors since the user could submit the button without selecting anything*/

var genre = 'racing';
var platform = 'xbox';

/* onload function */
$(function(){

/* grabs the array of elements in the HTML document that will be changed */

var gameTitle = $('.theGame');
var gameDesc = $('.desc');
var gamePic = $('.pic');

$("#platformType").change(function(){
  platform=$(this).val()
});

$("#genreType").change(function(){
  genre=$(this).val()
});

/* you only need one 'click' function for '#Submit' */

$("#Submit").click(function(){
console.log(genre, gameTitle, gameDesc, gamePic);
var matchedGames = games.filter((gameObject) => gameObject.genre==genre&&gameObject.platform==platform);

/* clearing out data first */
  for (i=0;i<gameTitle.length;i++) {
    gameTitle[i].innerHTML="";
    gameDesc[i].innerHTML="";
    gamePic[i].src="";
  }

/* then adding the filtered list of games into the page */
  for (i=0;i<matchedGames.length;i++) {
    gameTitle[i].innerHTML=matchedGames[i].name;
    gameDesc[i].innerHTML=matchedGames[i].descr;
    gamePic[i].src=matchedGames[i].imgr;
  }


});


});
```

Updated HTML:

```
<fieldset>
  <input type="submit" value="Find Game" id="Submit" />
  <select name="filterGame" id="platformType">
    <option value="" disabled class="option1">Select</option>
    <option value="xbox">xBox</option>
    <option value="xbox">Play Station</option>
  </select>
  <select name="filterGame" id="genreType">
    <option value="" disabled class="option1">Select</option>
    <option value="racing">Racing</option>
    <option value="racing">RPG</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>
<!-- added elements to work with the filter function, this can be done a few different ways -->
  <div>
    <h2 class="theGame"></h2>
    <img class="pic" src="">
    <p class="desc"></p>
    <h2 class="theGame"></h2>
    <img class="pic" src="">
    <p class="desc"></p>
    <h2 class="theGame"></h2>
    <img class="pic" src="">
    <p class="desc"></p>
    <h2 class="theGame"></h2>
    <img class="pic" src=""/>
    <p class="desc"></p>
</div>
```

In the JS:

- `filter()` returns an array, and cannot be used to make changes on a page (such as using .innerHTML),
- 'false' doesn't have to be explicitly declared (so the ternary operator isn't necessary here), because if an array element doesn't fulfill the requirement, then it will not be included in the returned array. This would be satisfactory:

```
var gameArr = games.filter((e)=>e.platform==platform && e.genre==genre);
```

- after the filter function is used to return a new array (matchedGames), this array is used to add data to the HTML elements I added in (the number of `<h2>` elements should match the total number of games if you opt to do it this way
- instead of coding the elements in manually one by one you could use the $('body').append() method to do something similar
- it is not necessary to add the game data to a `<h2>` or `<p>` elements, you could also add the data and images to a table for example, and achieve a similar result
- you will also need some way to clear out the data from previous entries whenever the user refilters the games, you could use a for loop to accomplish this, I added one in above as an example

In the HTML:

- I used `<h2>` elements instead of `<h1>` there should technically only be one `<h1>` element in a page, which should be the title to make your page screen-reading friendly

Hope this helps you on your coding quest!

Comment: Sorry I added some code last minute. Wow that clears a lot of things up. Thank you so much for teaching me. I think I can incorporate that into my code.